# How to use conditions while operating on dataframes in julia

Tags: statistics, julia, mean

I am trying to find the mean value of the dataframe's elements in corresponding to particular column when either of the condition is true. For example:

```
Using Statistics
df = DataFrame(value, xi, xj)
resulted_mean = []

for i in range(ncol(df))
push!(resulted_mean, mean(df[:value], (:xi == i | :xj == i)))
```

Here, I am checking when either `xi` or `xj` is equal to `i` then find the mean of the all the corresponding values stored in [:value] column. This mean will later be pushed to the array -> `resulted_mean`

However, this code is not producing the desired output.

Please suggest the optimal approach to fix this code snippet.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code is a mixture of Julia and Python and would not work at all. If you want to learn how to use DataFrames.jl I recommend you to check out the tutorials listed [here](https://dataframes.juliadata.org/latest/). I would like to help you but could you please show a sample input and a desired output of what you want as given your code it is hard to judge what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Bogumił's comment, you should really consult the Julia documentation to get a basic understanding of the language, and then run through the DataFrames tutorials. I will however annotate your code to point out some of the issues so you might be able to target your learning a bit better:

```
Using Statistics
```

Julia (like most other languages) is case sensitive, so writing `Using`is not the same as the reserved keyword `using` which is used to bring package definitions into your namespace. The relevant docs entry is [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#using)

Note also that you are using the DataFrames package, so to make your code reproducible you would have had to do `using DataFrames, Statistics`.

```
df = DataFrame(value, xi, xj)
```

It's unclear what this line is supposed to do as the arguments passed to the constructor are undefined, but assuming `value`, `xi` and `xj` are vectors of numbers, this isn't a correct way to construct a `DataFrame`:

```
julia> value = rand(10); xi = repeat(1:2, 5); xj = rand(1:2, 10);

julia> df = DataFrame(value, xi, xj)
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching DataFrame(::Vector{Float64}, ::Vector{Int64}, ::Vector{Int64})
```

You can read about constructors in the docs [here](https://dataframes.juliadata.org/stable/lib/types/#DataFrames.DataFrame), the most common approach for a DataFrame with only few columns like here would probably be:

```
julia> df = DataFrame(value = value, xi = xi, xj = xj)
10×3 DataFrame
 Row │ value     xi     xj    
     │ Float64   Int64  Int64 
─────┼────────────────────────
   1 │ 0.539533      1      2
   2 │ 0.652752      2      1
   3 │ 0.481461      1      2
...
```

Then you have

```
resulted_mean = []
```

I would say in this case the overall approach of preallocating a vector and pushing to it in a loop isn't ideal as it adds a lot of verbosity for no reason (see below), but as a general remark you should avoid untyped arrays in Julia:

```
julia> resulted_mean = []
Any[]
```

Here the `Any` means that the array can hold values of any type (floating point numbers, integers, strings, probability distributions...), which means the compiler cannot anticipate what the actual content will be from looking at the code, leading to suboptimal machine code being generated. In doing so, you negate the main advantage that Julia has over e.g. base Python: the rich type system combined with a lot of compiler optimizations allow generation of highly efficient machine code while keeping the language dynamic. In this case, you know that you want to push the results of the `mean` function to the results vector, which will be a floating point number, so you should use:

```
julia> resulted_mean = Float64[]
Float64[]
```

That said, I wouldn't recommend pushing in a loop here at all (see below).

Your loop is:

```
for i in range(ncol(df))
    ...
```

A few issues with this:

- Loops in Julia require an `end`, unlike in Python where their end is determined based on code indentation
- `range` is a different function in Julia than in Python:

```
julia> range(5)
ERROR: ArgumentError: At least one of `length` or `stop` must be specified
```

You can learn about functions using the REPL help mode (type `?` at the REPL prompt to access it):

```
help?> range
search: range LinRange UnitRange StepRange StepRangeLen trailing_zeros AbstractRange trailing_ones OrdinalRange AbstractUnitRange AbstractString

  range(start[, stop]; length, stop, step=1)

  Given a starting value, construct a range either by length or from start to stop, optionally with a given step (defaults to 1, a UnitRange). One of length or stop is required. If length, stop, and step are all specified, they must
  agree.
...
```

So you'd need to do something like

```
julia> range(1, 5, step = 1)
1:1:5
```

That said, for simple ranges like this you can use the colon operator: `1:5` is the same as `range(1, 5, step = 1).

- You then iterate over integers from 1 to `ncol(df)` - you might want to check whether this is what you're actually after, as it seems unusual to me that the values in the `xi` and `xj` columns (on which you filter in the loop) would be related to the number of columns in your DataFrame (which is 3).

In the loop, you do

```
push!(resulted_mean, mean(df[:value], (:xi == i | :xj == i)))
```

which again has a few problems: first of all you are passing the subsetting condition for your DataFrame to the `mean` function, which doesn't work:

```
julia> mean(rand(10), rand(Bool, 10))
ERROR: MethodError: objects of type Vector{Float64} are not callable
```

The subsetting condition itself has two issues as well: when you write `:xi`, there is no way for Julia to know that you are referring to the DataFrame column `xi`, so all you're doing is comparing the Symbol `:xi` to the value of `i`, which will always return false:

```
julia> :xi == 2
false
```

Furthermore, note that `|` has a higher precedence than `==`, so if you want to combine two equality checks with or you need brackets:

```
julia> 1 == 1 | 2 == 2
false

julia> (1 == 1) | (2 == 2)
true
```

More things could be said about your code snippet, but I hope this gives you an idea of where your gaps in understanding are and how you might go about closing them.

For completeness, here's how I would approach your problem - I'm interpreting your code to mean "calculate the mean of the `value` column, grouped by each value of `xi` and `xj`, but only where `xi` equals `xj`":

```
julia> combine(groupby(df[df.xi .== df.xj, :], [:xi, :xj], sort = true), :value => mean => :resulted_mean)
2×3 DataFrame
 Row │ xi     xj     resulted_mean 
     │ Int64  Int64  Float64       
─────┼─────────────────────────────
   1 │     1      1       0.356811
   2 │     2      2       0.977041
```

This is probably the most common analysis pattern for DataFrames, and is explained in the tutorial that Bogumił mentioned as well as in the DataFrames docs [here](https://dataframes.juliadata.org/stable/man/split_apply_combine/).

As I said up front, if you want to use Julia productively, I recommend that you spend some time reading the documentation both for the language itself as well as for any of the key packages you're using. While Julia has some similarities to Python, and some bits in the DataFrames package have an API that resemble things you might have seen in R, it is a language in its own right that is fundamentally different from both Python and R (or any other language for that matter), and there's no way around familiarizing yourself with how it actually works.